# NextJS MUI props geting overwritten from normal css

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, material-ui, frontend

I am currently tranfering my CRA project into a NextJS app. Unfortunately I am facing a weird bug. The MUI props get overwritten from the globals.css file. I would like to fix this issue so the css class is not overwritting the MUI pros anymore.

The css class is called default-flex:

```
.default-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Example MUI code:

```
<Box sx={{display: {xs: "flex", lg: "none"}}} className='default-flex'>
  <Button variant='contained'}>Click me!</Button>
</Box>
```

Also, if I would add something like `justifyContent: "left"` to the Box, the css class would overwrite it with `justify-content: space-between;`

What happens when running this code is that the Box is always visible (display is flex coming from the css class). It should normally only be visible on xs devices.

I was following this tutorial => https://dev.to/hajhosein/nextjs-mui-v5-tutorial-2k35

Template repo => https://github.com/HPouyanmehr/muxt

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: I don't understand, you're using `className`, it is said in the doc that if you use that it will override css : https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#overriding-styles-with-class-names

Comment: I created the app with CRA but decided to tranfer it to NextJS. So I started copying the components into the NextJS app. Everything worked in the CRA but in the NextJS app are all component props overwritten by css.

Comment: With CRA it should have been the same